# current date and current date + 1month

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, yii

I'm having trouble saving the date and time in mysql  using Yii.

My table contains (among other field define in Mysql table)

```
   fromDate datetime
    toDate datetime
    create datetime
    modified datetime
```

it works until I add `fromDate` and `toDate`

in my model, in the beforeValidate method,  I have the following lines

```
if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->created = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            $this->fromDate = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            $this->toDate = new CDBExpression('NOW()+ INSTANCE 1 MONTH');
} else {
            $this->modified = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
        }
        return parent::beforeValidate();
    }
```

and I got an error  The format of From Date is invalid.

I must add that in my rules,  I check whether the toDate is greater than fromDate

```
array('toDate','compare','compareAttribute' => 'fromDate','operator'=>'>', 'allowEmpty'=>'false', 'message' => '{attribute} should be greater than "{compareValue}".'),
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found that deleting the rule,

```
array('fromDate', 'date'),
```

it works,

sorry for the question